# CamlQuery does not seem to return the value from LookupColumn

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, csom, lookup-column, caml-query

The below code work for all the Columns except for `Publication` which is a Lookup.

The If `publicationField` is ALWAYS Null...ideas?

```
      // Assume the web has a list named "ADMPANewsAlertsWebAPI". 
        List announcementsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(SharePointConnector.sp_NewsAlerts_list);

        // This creates a CamlQuery that has a RowLimit of 100, and also specifies Scope="RecursiveAll" 
        // so that it grabs all list items, regardless of the folder they are in.                 
        CamlQuery CamlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        string qs =
            "<View><ViewFields>" +
                "<FieldRef Name='to' />" +
                "<FieldRef Name='url' />" +
                "<FieldRef Name='subject' />" +
                "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                "<FieldRef Name='source' />" +
                "<FieldRef Name='Created' />" +
                "<FieldRef Name='userid' />" +
                "<FieldRef Name='Category' />" +
                "<FieldRef Name='comments' />" +
                "<FieldRef Name='Publication' />" +
            "</ViewFields></View>";
        CamlQuery.ViewXml = qs;

        ListItemCollection items = announcementsList.GetItems(CamlQuery);

        // Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query). 
        clientContext.Load(items);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        var list = new List<Business.Entities.api.newsalert>();
        foreach (ListItem listItem in items)
        {
            var foo = new Business.Entities.api.newsalert();
            foo.to = listItem["to"] == null ? String.Empty : listItem["to"].ToString();
            foo.url = listItem["url"] == null ? String.Empty : listItem["url"].ToString();
            foo.subject = listItem["subject"] == null ? String.Empty : listItem["subject"].ToString();
            foo.title = listItem["Title"] == null ? String.Empty : listItem["Title"].ToString();
            foo.source = listItem["source"] == null ? String.Empty : listItem["source"].ToString();
            foo.timestamp = Offset(Convert.ToDateTime(listItem["Created"].ToString()));
            foo.userid = listItem["userid"] == null ? String.Empty : listItem["userid"].ToString();
            foo.categories = listItem["Category"] == null ? String.Empty : listItem["Category"].ToString();
            foo.comments = listItem["comments"] == null ? String.Empty : listItem["comments"].ToString();

            var publicationField = listItem["Publication"] as FieldLookupValue[];

                if (publicationField != null)  //<--- This line always Null
                {
                    foreach (var lookupValue in publicationField)
                    {
                        var publication_Value = lookupValue.LookupValue;
                        var publication_Id = lookupValue.LookupId;

                        foo.publication = publication_Value;
                    }
                }
            list.Add(foo);
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it looks the `Publication` field is a `Lookup field with Multiple Allow multiple values`.

So I simulated your code on my side and found out the following

- There is no issue in CAML Query.
- You can retrieve multiple lookup field values as the below code.
- The Lookup `publicationField` field is always **null** in case it actually don't have a value.

**Retrieve the Multiple Lookup field value and bind it to Grid view**

```
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Publication' /> </ViewFields></View>";
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.Load(collListItem);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            DataTable dtAudit = new DataTable();
            dtAudit.Columns.Add("Multi-Lookup-FieldValue", typeof(System.String));
            foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
            {
                var publicationField = oListItem["Publication"] as FieldLookupValue[];

                if (publicationField != null)
                {

                    foreach (var lookupValue in publicationField)
                    {
                        DataRow dRow = dtAudit.NewRow();
                        var publication_Value = lookupValue.LookupValue;
                        var publication_Id = lookupValue.LookupId;
                        dRow["Multi-Lookup-FieldValue"] = publication_Value;
                        dtAudit.Rows.Add(dRow);
                    }
                }

            }

            GridView1.DataSource = dtAudit;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

**Output**

[image]

---

Base on my code and the attached output, it should be working on your side, So  try to do the following:

- Make sure that Lookup `publicationField` field has a value.
- Try to replace my code on your side and debug it.

---

**Regarding the Lookup field value without multiple values you should use the following:**

```
    publicationField = listItem["Publication"] as FieldLookupValue;
       if (publicationField != null)
          {
             foo.publication = publicationField.LookupValue;

          }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the same results.  Also, my column does NOT have Allow Mutliple Values turned on.  There is content in the Publication column

Comment: wait please! are you sure column does NOT have Allow Mutliple Values turned on !

Comment: So your code is not correct? let me provide you the correct code for lookup column without multiple value

Comment: no need for for each and FieldLookupValue[] array here, because the lookup field without multiple value, so your code should like 
var publicationField = oListItem["Publication"] as FieldLookupValue;
                var publication_Value = publicationField.LookupValue;

Comment: please feedback me the result!

Comment: unfortunately, that returns publicationField.LookupValue = 'publicationField.LookupValue' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Comment: do you remove this [], are you sure you have value in this field

Comment: Quite right, there were new entries since I posted this last week and their Publication was blank.  I did this and now it works -                     var publicationField = listItem["Publication"] as FieldLookupValue;
                    if (publicationField != null)
                    {
                        var publication_Value = publicationField.LookupValue;
                        foo.publication = publication_Value;

Comment: glad to hear it working please Mark and upvote my anwer :) thank you